Why does my Tikkun not have Chapter 19 (yud tet)?
I noticed my Artscroll Tikkun does not display certain chapters numbers correctly.
Yud heh -> vuv?
Yud vuv -> tet zayn (this makes sense)
Yud chet -> chet (18 is lucky, so why isn't this allowed?)
Yud tet -> tet (huh???)
I am most confused about 19 (yud tet). What is so bad about these numbers and why are they “fixed” in such inconsistent ways?
Bonus Q: the corner of my Tikkun still uses the normal numbers. Why does the Artscroll Tikkun allow that but not the chapters in the text itself???

This happens  in every book of the Torah, or a specific one?

The printing was probably off a bit so that the yud got printed off the margins of the page.
